# Any drawbacks to leaving the selector of routed components in place?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In the Angular [routing documentation - Add heroes functionality](https://angular.io/guide/router#add-heroes-functionality) part of the instructions say to:

> Make a few minor but necessary changes:
>
> ```
> -Delete the selector (routed components don't need them).
> -Delete the <h1>.
> ```

Seems like it would be a good idea to just leave the selector in place so that component can be used in both in routing and non routing contexts?

Any drawbacks to just leaving it in place?

The documentation examples for components used in the demo do actually delete the selector within the `@Component` decorator as is done for the `CrisisCenterComponent` example below (Taken directly from the router documentation):

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
   template: `<p>Welcome to the Crisis Center</p>`
 })
 export class CrisisCenterHomeComponent { }
```

So in this case suppose we refactor the app and place `CrisisCenterComponent` in a shared module and use that component in multiple views/pages where we need to sometimes use the element name (Selector) and other times the router.  Removing the `selector` makes this impossible right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no drawbacks to leaving the selector in the component.

Comment: I updated the link to point directly to the heading from where I copied and pasted.

Comment: i know where you were looking at. Edited the answer to be more specific

Comment: You could also leave the selector, is not an error. but is not a best practise, because in some cases (like prerendering) angular could read that as a no-routing component, so you could have two equal components created but you'll use only one.

Comment: I updated the question to provide a fuller context.  Not sure we are talking about the same section yet.

Comment: Yes, the section is exactly that one

Comment: OK - Cool - So they are not saying delete the selector from the compnent's definition.  The are saying delete the element from the file containing the outlet so that the routed element does not show up twice?

Comment: Exactly! But if you don’t import the component in the previously module (another change that they say to do) you will also have an error, because the selector is not defined anymore! So, delete selector from html file AND from component definition (you could leave the second one, but is not good practise as explained before) and you’ll have the component loaded with routing

Comment: I'm still a little confused here because later on I noticed the components do have the selector removed from the @Component decorator?  I updated the question with an example.  I'm assuming that leaving the selector in the component would allow the usage of the component in both a view context and a routing context, but if we remove the selector then the component can only be used in a routing context?

Comment: In your answer you are saying what the documentation is saying, which is that we don't need the selector anymore.  However my question ask whether there are any drawbacks to just leaving the selector in the component ...

Comment: I have a project with a component loaded with routing but the selector still persist in @component decorator; But when i did the prerendering build i had to leave that because it caused racing conditions. So You could leave it inside decorator, you could use it in a view AND with routing, but is not a best practise!

Comment: I just want to add something to my previous comment: you have to remember to import the component MODULE where you use it in view (html calling it with selector) and to load with routing the module where you want to navigate. In second case, you'll see only the component view, without everything else outside the selector (obviously you still see what is outside `router-outlet` present in `app.component.html`)

Comment: I'm still quite confused.  What if someone publishes a component like https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar and we want to use that.  It has the selector built in.  Will we start seeing issues now?

Comment: Like they uses it, the selector is called inside demo.html, so is not loaded with routing. Is that your question?

Comment: Take a look at the component example in the question.  The selector is removed from the @Component decorator.  My question is whether there are any drawbacks to leaving it in?

Comment: No, there aren’t.